# UIKit: Expanding a circular UIView

Tags: uiview, ios8, uikit, swift2, ios9

I am looking for an answer written in Swift 2.0 that works with iOS 8.0 or later. I have a circular `UIView` and I want to expand it but keep the properties of a circle.

To set up the `UIView` this is the code.

```
let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)
let view: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
```

Comment: Can you post some code? How do you create your circular view?

Comment: Let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10).  Let view = UIView(frame: frame).         view.layer.cornerRadius = 5. Sorry for the formatting I am on mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to expand your circle view you can transform its scale:

```
circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)
```

You can animate the change:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { () -> Void in
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)
}
```

And if you want to expand the button only shortly and then have it go back to its original size you can chain two animations:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)
}) { (finished) -> Void in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: That expands the view but the corner radius doesn't maintain the view as a circle.

Comment: Yes it does. Please have a look at the animated gif.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I found your answer to be correct and have improved my question to add code.  If you think my question was a good one I appreciate and up vote.